# ReactQuery: use multiple QueryClients with different settings?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-query

I have a React SPA, where I am trying to use the `ReactQuery` library. I fetch a lot of different data from my server API - some are more volatile, others are relatively stable. I would like to store the stable data in the browser's local storage, in order to reduce the number of requests made to the server (and thus making the UI app a bit faster) and refresh them every 24 hours. However, I want to invalidate and re-fetch the volatile data with every request, because other users might have changed the data in the meantime.

Currently, I have just a simple ReactQueryProvider wrapped around my App:

```
import React from 'react';
import { QueryClientProvider } from 'react-query';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import { CookiesProvider } from 'react-cookie';
import { QueryClient } from 'react-query';
import { HttpError } from 'types';

const MaxFailureCount = 2;
const baseUrl = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].getAttribute('href') || undefined;
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');

function shouldRetry(failureCount: number, error: unknown): boolean {
  if (error instanceof HttpError) {
    if (!error.isRetryableError()) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return failureCount < MaxFailureCount;
}
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
    defaultOptions: {
      queries: {
        refetchOnMount: false,
        refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
        refetchOnReconnect: false,
        retry: shouldRetry,
      },
    },
  });

ReactDOM.render(
  <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
    <BrowserRouter basename={baseUrl}>
      <CookiesProvider>
        <App />
      </CookiesProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </QueryClientProvider>,
  rootElement
);
```

If I wanted to use the [persistQueryClient](https://react-query.tanstack.com/plugins/persistQueryClient) plugin, I would have to add a `cacheTime` to my `queryClient` and then pass the client to a `localStoragePersistor`. If I understand the documentation correctly, this would change all my `useQuery` calls to store the data in local storage for 24 hours - even the data which are more volatile.

There is the option to pass a `buster` string to the persisted cache, but that would invalidate all the data (even the stable). Is there a way to use two different `queryClients`? Or, to specify in each `useQuery` call whether the response should be cached, or not? Or should I put the response of my stable data API into a local storage manually? If so, how do I handle the invalidation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I decided to create my own hook with local storage. It was quite easy and I can re-use the defaul `QueryClient` without any additional configuration:

```
import { HttpError } from 'types';
import { useQuery, UseQueryOptions } from 'react-query';
import { get } from 'utils/request';

const defaultStaleTime = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 24 hours

type CachedQueryProps<T> = {
  path: string;
  staleTime?: number | null | undefined;
  forceRefresh?: boolean | null | undefined;
  options?: UseQueryOptions<T, HttpError, T> | undefined;
};

type CachedQueryResult<T> = {
  data: T | undefined;
  isLoading: boolean;
  error: HttpError | null;
};

type CachedObject<T> = {
  data: T;
  refreshTime: number;
};

export function useCachedQuery<T>(props: CachedQueryProps<T>): CachedQueryResult<T> {
  const now = new Date().getTime();
  const lowestAllowedTime = now - (props.staleTime ?? defaultStaleTime);
  const item = window.localStorage.getItem(props.path);
  const result = (item && (JSON.parse(item) as CachedObject<T> | null)) || null;
  const refresh = !result || result.refreshTime < lowestAllowedTime || !!props.forceRefresh;
  const query = useQuery<T, HttpError>(props.path, () => get<T>(props.path), { ...props.options, enabled: refresh });

  if (query.isSuccess) {
    const newData = { data: query.data, refreshTime: now };
    localStorage.setItem(props.path, JSON.stringify(newData));
    return query;
  }

  return { data: result?.data, isLoading: false, error: null };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the QueryClient is just a vessel that holds the queryCache, the mutationCache and the default settings. If you want to create a new QueryClient, and copy over the caches, you can set new default settings and still keep the cache.

A rudimentary implementation would be:

```
const ReactQueryConfigProvider = ({ children, defaultOptions }) => {
    const client = useQueryClient()
    const [newClient] = React.useState(
        () =>
            new QueryClient({
                queryCache: client.getQueryCache(),
                muationCache: client.getMutationCache(),
                defaultOptions,
            })
    )
    return <QueryClientProvider client={newClient}>{children}</QueryClientProvider>
}
```

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-query-config-provider-v3-lt00f) where this is used in action (I've taken this from my blog: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/testing-react-query). Not sure if this will help you with the persistQueryClient problem, but if you just want to change the `cacheTime` for some parts of the componentTree, this'll do.

Comment: Not sure why, but it doesn't really work. When I open browser's developer tools, I can see the data in the Local storage. However, when I hit F5, the query still calls the backend API and I can see the timestamp increase.

Comment: I think you are mixing things up here. You asked about `cacheTime`, but could it be that you actually want to customize `staleTime` ? it looks like your component mounts, you get the data from the cache correctly and then you get a background refetch because of the default `staleTime` of `0`.

Comment: Even when defining both `cacheTime` and `staleTime`, the local storage is updated with every F5 refresh. I am not exactly sure which options I have to define. The thing I am asking about is: " *I would like to store the stable data in the browser's local storage, in order to reduce the number of requests made to the server (and thus making the UI app a bit faster) and refresh them every 24 hours. However, I want to invalidate and re-fetch the volatile data with every request, because other users might have changed the data in the meantime.* "